# Is it possible to have 2 get queries in 1 route in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

right now I am struggling with a small problem and I don't know if it is even possible to do.

So I am building a website where users store their contacts and I want to get the contact by it's ID with url/contacts/:id .
But I also want to get all contacts of one user when I do: url/contacts?userId=*aUserID*

So right now my routes look like this:

```
router.route("/")
    .get(ContactsController.showAll)  // show all contacts from all users
    .post(ContactsController.postContact)
 //   .get(ContactsController.getUsersContacts);  // and this should be all users from one user

router.route("/:id")
    .get(ContactsController.getContact) //get Contact by its ID
    .put(ContactsController.putContact)
    .delete(ContactsController.deleteContact);
```

Here is the Controller Code:

```
getContact: async (req, res, next) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    const contact = await Contact.findById(id);
    res.status(200).json(contact);
},

getUsersContacts: async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.query.userId).populate("contacts");
    res.send(user)
}
```

The getusersContacts just works correctly, when I comment out the "*showAll*"-Method in the routes.

I know I could make a new route and get the users contacts at /users/contacts?userId=... but I want to use the same route if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those are not one route. Those are two very different routes. The key is to make sure that the `/` route does not match the `/:id` route so you need to rearrange which gets checked first:

```
// Check this first since `/` does not match this route
router.route("/:id")
    .get(ContactsController.getContact) //get Contact by its ID
    .put(ContactsController.putContact)
    .delete(ContactsController.deleteContact);

router.route("/")
    .get(ContactsController.showAll)  // show all contacts from all users
    .post(ContactsController.postContact)
 //   .get(ContactsController.getUsersContacts);  // and this should be all users from one user
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that those are two different routes. But right now my "/" has just one .get to get all contacts at /contacts but I want it to also use the 2nd get when I type in url/contacts?userId="id" to get all contacts of a specific user.

Comment: So you just want to return different result based on query params? Sure. You can do that. Facebook for example wrote an entire API where you can ask for anything using just one url but different request body